# How to change AIX machine number (uname -m)

Tags: aix, uname

On an AIX system the `uname -m` command "Displays the machine ID number of the hardware running the system."

Where does uname get this information from ? I need to change it and I can't find any documentation on where the value comes from.

This is specific to AIX because other flavors on unix act differently. It can't be a baked in value because it behaves differently on different machines. It is somehow related to the CPU.

Comment: I re-wrote the question to get rid of fluff. This is the core issue I need to address.

Comment: No, you don't need to change it.

Comment: Actually I do need to change it. I am asking how.

Comment: Mayhaps you are trying to run a software on a computer you don't have the licence to do so?

Comment: Lorinczy - snarky though your comment is, I have a license but the software is node locked and the machine is dead. The original publisher went out of business. Perhaps you could provide a helpful comment?

Comment: Well, uname(1) _program_ uses uname(2) _system-call_ which you cannot redirect/hook -- tricks like LD_PRELOAD doesn't work on AIX.

Comment: Is this a LPAR?

Comment: No. Just out of the box hardware/AIX.